# WordPress mode for emacs?

Tags: plugin-development, coding-standards

Is anyone using emacs for editing WordPress and have a mode that follow the code style guidelines that they would care to share? If so I would appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

WordPress coding standards are loosely based on the [Pear Coding Standards](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.php)
The Drupal open source project also follows similar standards and has published a [guide to configuring various editors and IDEs](http://drupal.org/node/59868) which includes code for a Emacs Drupal mode which can be modified slightly for WordPress.